# Javascript Countdown changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, countdowntimer

I'm basically using a javascript countdown for one of my websites, it contains everything i need, however i want to expand on it but i am relatively new to js. Basically, it shows a message once the countdown has completed which is great, however i want to show a message alongside the countdown which is removed with the countdown when it reaches 0.

Example: "New Year in, {Countdown}" so the new year text along with the countdown should be removed when it hits 0 and replaced with the finished text.

Here is the script i am using:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = "January/01/2014 12:00 am";
BackColor = "";
ForeColor = "#000";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "<span class='finish'>Finished!</span>";
</script>
<script language="javascript">
function calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
  s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
  if (LeadingZero && s.length < 2)
    s = "0" + s;
  return "<span class='digit'>" + s + "</span>";
}

function CountBack(secs) {
  if (secs < 0) {
    document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = FinishMessage;
    return;
  }
  DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g, calcage(secs,86400,100000));
  DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, calcage(secs,3600,24));
  DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, calcage(secs,60,60));
  DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, calcage(secs,1,60));

  document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = DisplayStr;
  if (CountActive)
    setTimeout("CountBack(" + (secs+CountStepper) + ")", SetTimeOutPeriod);
}

function putspan(backcolor, forecolor) {
 document.write("<span id='cntdwn' style=' font-weight:bold; background-color:" + backcolor + 
                "; color:" + forecolor + "'> </span>");
}

if (typeof(BackColor)=="undefined")
  BackColor = "white";
if (typeof(ForeColor)=="undefined")
  ForeColor= "black";
if (typeof(TargetDate)=="undefined")
  TargetDate = "12/31/2020 5:00 AM";
if (typeof(DisplayFormat)=="undefined")
  DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
if (typeof(CountActive)=="undefined")
  CountActive = true;
if (typeof(FinishMessage)=="undefined")
  FinishMessage = "";
if (typeof(CountStepper)!="number")
  CountStepper = -1;
if (typeof(LeadingZero)=="undefined")
  LeadingZero = true;


CountStepper = Math.ceil(CountStepper);
if (CountStepper == 0)
  CountActive = false;
var SetTimeOutPeriod = (Math.abs(CountStepper)-1)*1000 + 990;
putspan(BackColor, ForeColor);
var dthen = new Date(TargetDate);
var dnow = new Date();
if(CountStepper>0)
  ddiff = new Date(dnow-dthen);
else
  ddiff = new Date(dthen-dnow);
gsecs = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
CountBack(gsecs);
</script>
```

Any help in getting this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: This is one bad script right there! I'll post a jQuery plugin for you in a moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your ansswer, excuse If I didnt get ur question right.

```
DisplayFormat = "New Year in, {%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds}.";
```

Comment: Wow, how simple, i tried everywhere else except there! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you've got the simple answer, but here's a jQuery plugin if you'd like to have it a bit cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdanek/C59hN/1/

Just target an element with date inside and will be turned into a counter

```
$('p.counter').countdownCounter({
    format : 'New Year in %%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds!',
});
```

**Edit:** I’ve created a separate page for the plugin http://cou.io/code/countdown/ and added a few options.